# Rails Load Paths in Heroku Production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm trying to use a service object I created within Action Cable Rails 5.1.3. It works in development but complains on Heroku production.

## ConversationsController

Where my application complains in production and not development.

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    @conversation = Stage::ConversationService.existing_conversation?
    ...
  end
end
```

## Here is the path to the service object.

```
app/lib/stage/conversation_service.rb
```

## Here is the service object:

```
module Stage
  class ConversationService
    DIRECT_CONVERSATION = 2

    def initialize(conversation)
      @conversation = conversation
    end

    def self.existing_conversation?(current_user, other_user)
      current_user.conversations.each do |conversation|
        next if conversation.user_conversations.count > DIRECT_CONVERSATION

        conversation.user_conversations.each do |user|
          return Conversation.find(user.conversation_id) if user.user_id == other_user.id
        end
      end
      nil
    end

    def self.new_conversation(current_user, other_user)
      conversation = Conversation.create!
      conversation.user_conversations.create!(user_id: current_user.id, conversation_id: conversation.id)
      conversation.user_conversations.create!(user_id: other_user.id, conversation_id: conversation.id)
      conversation
    end
  end
end
```

## Heroku Logs

Here's where Heroku complains `NameError (uninitialized constant ConversationsController::Stage):`

```
018-02-16T02:18:41.662824+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/conversations" host=primetimetran.com request_id=1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7 fwd="14.226.243.186,162.158.178.181" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=10ms status=500 bytes=1827 protocol=http
2018-02-16T02:18:41.655273+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7] Started POST "/conversations" for 162.158.178.181 at 2018-02-16 02:18:41 +0000
2018-02-16T02:18:41.656695+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7] Processing by ConversationsController#create as HTML
2018-02-16T02:18:41.656740+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"SyLFqMPRJQswBgqso+6VsVsiCdWDUuaXeL54d2SCH/tKwKFLAL29JQCgTzxbHbO48CtJLDg9lfUPcdpiu5ac8w==", "conversation"=>{"user_id"=>"1"}}
2018-02-16T02:18:41.661315+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 4ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2018-02-16T02:18:41.661721+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7]
2018-02-16T02:18:41.661786+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7] NameError (uninitialized constant ConversationsController::Stage):
2018-02-16T02:18:41.661806+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7]
2018-02-16T02:18:41.661830+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7] app/controllers/conversations_controller.rb:5:in `create'
2018-02-16T02:18:41.661831+00:00 app[web.1]: [1696e60d-8284-40ae-94a0-2491822affb7] app/middleware/chat_action_cable.rb:10:in `call'
```

## Application.rb

I feel like I'm suppose to do something here in production for custom service objects...? I don't know, that's just my guess.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

require_relative 'boot'
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Humanbook
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Initialize configuration defaults for originally generated Rails version.
    config.load_defaults 5.1

    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: true, views: false
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot, dir: 'spec/factories'
    end

    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.
    config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')

    config.action_mailer.asset_host = 'http://locahost:3000'
    config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

    ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
      user_name: ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
      password: ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
      api_key: ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY'],
      domain: 'http://locahost:3000',
      address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
      port: 587,
      authentication: :plain,
      enable_starttls_auto: true
    }
    config.time_zone = 'Asia/Bangkok'
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try prepending your constant name with `::` like this:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    ...
    @conversation = ::Stage::ConversationService.existing_conversation?
    ...
  end
end
```

The error suggests the constant lookup is occurring in the `ConversationController` namespace. The `::` will force the constant lookup to start in the global namespace.

I put my services under `app/services`. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Also, I typically do:

```
class Stage::ConversationService
  ...
end
```

Instead of:

```
module Stage
  class ConversationService
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I did that, now it complains: 
`2018-02-16T06:10:10.096118+00:00 app[web.1]: [28ab2446-e1b7-4fd3-9906-a3c013e61629] NameError (uninitialized constant Stage):`

Comment: The latter of the 2 class definitions is generally considered good practice. See: https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#namespace-definition

Comment: In the ~2.5 years since I wrote this answer, I have been slowly merging toward the latter. So, thank you for the reference.